# How to use a while loop and None function properly?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, python-3.x, while-loop

Hello guys i have been trying to make this program so their are no glitches or cheats in it.  I just can not figure our how to use a while loop on line [] so that if nothing is entered the program does not continue to operate.

```
#Running pertty good but needs work!
#charector creator program v3
#values
def getString(prompt):
    result = input(prompt)
    while len(result) == 0:
        result = input(prompt)
    return result

def Character_Creator_Function():
    NAME = getString("Please enter your name: ")
    if (input("Would you like instructions?(y,n): ") in ['y','Y']):
        printInstructions()
    print("Welcome",NAME)
    stats=[NAME, "HP", "STR", "AC", "DAM" "LCK", "DEF"]
    HP=0
    STR=0
    AC=0
    DAM=0
    LCK=0
    DEF=0
    #interface begins
    op=31
    points=30
    choice=None
    print("Welcome to the Charector Creater Program!")
    while choice!="0":
        print("\nYou have",points,"points to spend on various stats!")
        #list below
        print(
            """
            1= Add points
            2= Take away points
            3= View Stats
            4= Begin Battle!
            """)
        choice=input("choice:")

        #choice 1
        if choice=="1":
            stats=input("""
            1- Health Points
            2- Strenght Points
            3- Armor Class Points
            4- Damage Points
            5- Luck Points
            6- defense Points
            """)
            add=int(input("how many points?"))
            if add<=points and add>0:
                if stats=="1":
                    HP+=add
                    print( HP, "= Health points.")
                elif stats=="2":
                    STR+=add
                    print( STR, "= Strenght points.")
                elif stats=="3":
                    AC+=add
                    print( AC, "= Aromor Class points.")
                elif stats=="4":
                    DAM+=add
                    print( DAM, "= Damage points.")    
                elif stats=="5":
                    LCK+=add
                    print( LCK, "= Luck points.")
                elif stats=="6":
                    DEF+=add
                    print( DEF, "= defense points.")
                points-=add
                print("you have", points)

            else:
                     print("""
                               Invalid answer!
                   You either do not have enought points.
                                     OR
                     You are entering a negitive number!
                     """)

    #choice 2
        if choice=="2":
            stats=input("""
            1- Health Points
            2- Strenght Points
            3- Armor Class Points
            4- Damage Points
            5- Luck Points
            6- defense Points
            """)
            take=input("how many points?")
            while take==0:
                if stats=="1" and take<=HP:
                    HP-=take #HP
                    print( HP, "= Health points.")
                elif stats=="2" and take<=STR:
                    STR-=take #STR
                    print( STR, "= Strenght points.")
                elif stats=="3" and take<=AC:
                    AC-=take #AC
                    print( AC, "= Aromor Class points.")
                elif stats=="4"and take<=DAM:
                    DAM-=take #DAM
                    print( DAM, "= Damage points.")    
                elif stats=="5"and take<=LCK:
                    LCK-=take #LCK
                    print( LCK, "= Luck points.")
                elif stats=="6"and take<=DEF:
                    DEF-=take #DEF
                    print( DEF, "= Defense points.")
                points+=take
            else:
                print("""
                               Invalid answer!
                    You are do not have that many points!
                               """)

       #choice 3
        if choice=="3":
             print("Health:", HP)
             print("Strenght:", STR)
             print("Armor Class:", AC)
             print("Damage:", DAM)
             print("Luck:", LCK)
             print("Defense:", DEF)

        #choice 4
        if choice=="4":
            print("You have Compleated your Charector creator program! Congradulations! you are now ready to begin battle! HuRa!")
            print("HP:",HP,"\nSTR:",STR,"\nAC:",AC,"\nDAM:",DAM,"\nLCK:",LCK,"\nDEF:",DEF ,"\n")
            return [NAME,HP,STR,AC,DAM,LCK,DEF]

        #for programmers use to navagate through out the program with ease
        if choice=="x":

            HP=1000
            STR=10
            AC=5
            DAM=10
            LCK=100
            DEF=5
            print("HP:",HP,"\nSTR:",STR,"\nAC:",AC,"\nDAM:",DAM,"\nLCK:",LCK,"\nDEF:",DEF ,"\n")
            print("You have Compleated your Charector creator program! Congradulations!")
            print("You are now ready to begin battle! HuRa!\n\n")
            return [NAME,HP,STR,AC,DAM,LCK,DEF]
Character_Creator_Function()
```

this is the error i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexmasse/Desktop/ExampleQuest final/Charector Creator 100% functions, NOT IDEAL.py", line 145, in <module>
    Character_Creator_Function()
  File "/Users/alexmasse/Desktop/ExampleQuest final/Charector Creator 100% functions, NOT IDEAL.py", line 49, in Character_Creator_Function
    add=int(input("how many points?"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

on line 49 i do need the `int(input("yadayadyad")` because if i don't have the int input it gives me a int>str can not do or some weird error like that.

PLEASE HELP!
ps. I'm fairly new to programming so could you use code to an extent and the translate into laymen's terms sort to speak, thank you :)

Comment: What did you feed as input, on line 49?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message quite plainly states the problem: the empty input cannot be converted to an `int`.  In general, you cannot assume the user will enter just a numeric string, so you need to cope somehow.

A common idiom is to wrap with an exception handler:

```
while True:
    try:
        add=int(input("How many points? "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```